# Adding UITableView programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, dynamic

I think I have looked through a lot of questions like mine but nothing seems to work.

I am sending request to the server and in the moment I get all the data, I am starting to fill my `ViewController` programmatically. And all this happening in main_queue

This is the code of adding table:

```
if  self.attachments.count > 0 {
        docTableView = UITableView(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: self.myView.frame.width, height: 500.0), style: UITableViewStyle.Plain)
        docTableView!.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        docTableView!.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "MenuCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "MenuCell")
        self.myView.addSubview(docTableView!)
        docTableView!.dataSource = self
        docTableView!.delegate = self

        self.myView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: docTableView!, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: subviews!.last, attribute: .Bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 5.0))
        self.myView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: docTableView!, attribute: .Leading, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self.headerStackView, attribute: .Leading, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0))

        self.docTableView?.reloadData()
        subviews?.append(docTableView!)
    }
```

Then, I realized that two methods have been called : `numberOfRowsInSection`, `heightForRowAtIndexPath` and even the count of elements is greater than 0.
But `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is not being called and I guess that the reason that I do not see the `tableView` at all.
So how can I get to it?

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    if tableView == self.docTableView {
         return attachments.count
    }
    else {
        return self.notificationViewModel!.comments.count
    }

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 100.0 // I add this to show that its not zero
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if tableView == self.docTableView {
        let object = attachments[indexPath.row]
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: object.Url!)!)

    }
}
```

So `commTableView` is the same as `docTableView`. I need both of them and they have the same problem.

EDIT: I have this hierarchy: `View->ScrollView->myView`

EDIT2: My ViewController code. I have different types of data to add but all of it needs tables of attachments and comments

```
class NotificationViewController: UIViewController, MarkChosenDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

//IBOutlets FROM STORYBOARD
@IBOutlet weak var myView: UIView!

@IBOutlet weak var headerStackView: UIStackView!
@IBOutlet weak var setMarkButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var placingWayCodeLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var leftDaysLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var typeLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var regionLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
@IBOutlet weak var notificationNameLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var markColorButton: UIButton!

var docTableView:UITableView?
var commTableView:UITableView?

var delegate:NewMarkSetProtocol?

var notificationViewModel: NotificationViewModel?

var attachments:[Attachment] = []

//FIELDS FOR SEGUE TO THE CUSTOMER
var customerGuid:String?
var customerName:String?
var inn:String?
var kpp:String?

let marks = DataClass.sharedInstance.marks

var viewUtils:ViewUtils?

var notificationItem: NotificationT? {
    didSet {
        self.setUpTheHeaderInformation()
    }
}

//VIEW CONTROLLER LIFE CYCLES METHODS
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.setUpTheHeaderInformation()

    viewUtils = ViewUtils()
    viewUtils?.showActivityIndicator(self.view)

    notificationViewModel = NotificationViewModel()
    notificationViewModel?.delegateComments = self
    notificationViewModel?.delegateInformation = self
    if (notificationItem != nil) {
        if UsefulClass.isConnectedToNetwork() == true {
            notificationViewModel!.getNotification(notificationItem!)
            notificationViewModel!.getComments((notificationItem?.NotificationGuid)!)
        } else {
            notificationViewModel!.getCoreNotification(notificationItem!)
        }
    }
    print(setMarkButton)

}

func setUpTheHeaderInformation() {

    if let notificationT = self.notificationItem {
        self.navigationItem.title = notificationT.OrderName
        self.notificationItem?.IsRead = true

        if let label = self.notificationNameLabel {
            label.text = notificationT.OrderName
            self.placingWayCodeLabel.text = notificationT.getPlacingWayId()
            self.leftDaysLabel.text = notificationT.getLeft()
            self.typeLabel.text = notificationT.getType()

            if (marks.count != 0) {
                var mark:MarkClass?

                for i in 0..<marks.count {
                    if (marks[i].Id == notificationT.MarkId) {
                        mark = marks[i]
                    }
                }

                if let _mark = mark {
                    self.setMarkButton.setTitle(String(_mark.Name!), forState: .Normal)
                    self.markColorButton.hidden = false
                    self.markColorButton.backgroundColor = UsefulClass.colorWithHexString(_mark.Color!)
                } else {
                    self.markColorButton.hidden = true
                }
            }
            if let code = notificationT.RegionCode {
                self.regionLabel.text = UsefulClass.regionByRegionCode(code)
            }
        }
    }
}


//TABLE VIEW
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    let count:Int = 2
    if tableView == self.docTableView {
        print(attachments.count)
        return attachments.count
    }
    if tableView == self.commTableView {
        return self.notificationViewModel!.comments.count
    }
    return count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 100.0
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if tableView == self.docTableView {
        let object = attachments[indexPath.row]
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: object.Url!)!)
    }
}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if tableView == self.docTableView {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("MenuCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MenuCell
        let object = attachments[indexPath.row]
        let endIndex = object.FileName!.endIndex.advancedBy(-4)
        let type:String = (object.FileName?.substringFromIndex(endIndex))!
        cell.imageMark.image = notificationViewModel!.getImageForAttachment(type)
        cell.name.text = object.FileName
        cell.count.text = ""

        return cell
    } else  {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CommentItemCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CommentTableViewCell
        let object = self.notificationViewModel!.comments[indexPath.row]
        if let name = object.getCreatorName() {
            cell.nameUser.text = name
        }
        cell.textComment.text = object.Text
        //cell.imageUser.image =
        cell.timeComment.text = object.getTime()
        return cell
    }
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    if tableView == self.commTableView {
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }
}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .Delete {
        Requests.deleteComment(notificationViewModel!.comments[indexPath.row].Id!, notificationGuid: (self.notificationItem?.NotificationGuid)!)
        notificationViewModel?.comments.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
        self.commTableView!.reloadData()
    } else {

    }
}

extension String {
func heightWithConstrainedWidth(width: CGFloat, font: UIFont) -> CGFloat {
    let constraintRect = CGSize(width: width, height: CGFloat.max)

    let boundingBox = self.boundingRectWithSize(constraintRect, options: NSStringDrawingOptions.UsesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: font], context: nil)

    return boundingBox.height
}
}

 extension NSAttributedString {
func heightWithConstrainedWidth(width: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
    let constraintRect = CGSize(width: width, height: CGFloat.max)
    let boundingBox = self.boundingRectWithSize(constraintRect, options: NSStringDrawingOptions.UsesLineFragmentOrigin, context: nil)

    return ceil(boundingBox.height)
}

func widthWithConstrainedHeight(height: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
    let constraintRect = CGSize(width: CGFloat.max, height: height)

    let boundingBox = self.boundingRectWithSize(constraintRect, options: NSStringDrawingOptions.UsesLineFragmentOrigin, context: nil)

    return ceil(boundingBox.width)
}
}

extension NotificationViewController:NotificationInformationUpdate {

func informationUpdate() {

    var subviews:[UIView]? = [UIView]()

    switch(notificationItem?.Type)! {
    case 0:

        let notification  = notificationViewModel?.notification as! Notification_223
        self.attachments = notification.attachments
        if let name = notification.TenderPlanOrganisationName {
            subviews = addTitleandValue("Заказчик", _value: name, _subviews: subviews!, numberOfLines: 0)
        }

        if let initialSum = notification.InitialSum {
            subviews = addTitleandValue("Цена контракта", _value: initialSum, _subviews: subviews!, numberOfLines: 0)
        } else if let maxPrice = notificationItem?.MaxPrice {
            subviews = addTitleandValue("Цена контракта", _value: UsefulClass.getMaxPrice(maxPrice), _subviews: subviews!, numberOfLines: 0)
        }

        break
    case 1:
        let notification = notificationViewModel?.notification as! Notification_44
        self.attachments = notification.attachments!
        let customerNameTitle = UILabel()
        customerNameTitle.text = "Заказчик:"
        customerNameTitle.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        customerNameTitle.textColor = UIColor.grayColor()
        setSimilarConstraintsToTitlesLabels(customerNameTitle,     relatedView: self.headerStackView)

        let customerName = UILabel()
        customerName.text = notification.TenderPlanOrganisationName
        customerName.textColor = UIColor.blueColor()
        customerName.userInteractionEnabled = true
        let tapGester = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:     #selector(NotificationViewController.customerNameClick(_:)))
        customerName.addGestureRecognizer(tapGester)
        subviews = setSimilarConstraintsToValuesLabels(customerName,    relatedView: customerNameTitle, _subViews: subviews!)

        if let maxprice = notificationItem?.MaxPrice {
            subviews = addTitleandValue("Цена контракта", _value: UsefulClass.getMaxPrice(maxprice), _subviews: subviews!, numberOfLines: 0)
        }

        break
    case 2:
        let notification = notificationViewModel?.notification as! B2BNotification
        self.attachments = notification.attachments
        subviews = addTitleandValue("Заказчик", _value: notification.TenderPlanOrganisationName!, _subviews: subviews!, numberOfLines: 0)

        if let priceTotal = notification.PriceTotal {
            var value = UsefulClass.getMaxPrice(priceTotal)
            if let pricevat = notification.PriceVAT {
                value.appendContentsOf(" (" +  pricevat + ")")
            }
            subviews = addTitleandValue("Начальная цена всего лота", _value: value, _subviews: subviews!, numberOfLines: 0)
        } else {
            subviews = addTitleandValue("Начальная цена всего лота", _value: "Отсутствует поле", _subviews: subviews!, numberOfLines: 0)
        }

        if let priceone = notification.PriceOne {
            subviews = addTitleandValue("Цена за единицу продукции", _value: UsefulClass.getMaxPrice(priceone), _subviews: subviews!, numberOfLines: 0)
        }
        break

    case 7, 17:

        let notification = notificationViewModel?.notification as! TakTorgNotification
        self.attachments = notification.attachments
        subviews = addTitleandValue("Наименование заказа", _value: notification.Subject!, _subviews: subviews!, numberOfLines: 0)

        if let procNumber = notification.ProcedureProcedureNumber {
            subviews = addTitleandValue("Номер закупки", _value: procNumber, _subviews: subviews!, numberOfLines: 0)
        } else if let procNumber2 = notification.ProcedureProcedureNumber2 {
            subviews = addTitleandValue("Номер закупки", _value: procNumber2, _subviews: subviews!, numberOfLines: 0)
        }

        if let startPrice = notification.StartPrice {
            subviews = addTitleandValue("Начальная цена", _value: UsefulClass.getMaxPrice(startPrice), _subviews: subviews!, numberOfLines: 0)
        }

        if let peretorgPossible = notification.ProcedurePeretorgPossible {
            subviews = addTitleandValue("Возможность проведения процедуры переторжки", _value: peretorgPossible, _subviews: subviews!, numberOfLines: 0)
        }

        if let negotiationPossible = notification.ProcedureNegotiationPossible {
            subviews = addTitleandValue("Возможность проведения переговоров", _value: negotiationPossible, _subviews: subviews!, numberOfLines: 0)
        }
        //….
        break
    default:
        break
    }


    let documentsTitle = UILabel()
    documentsTitle.text = "Документы закупки"
    documentsTitle.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    documentsTitle.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    documentsTitle.font = documentsTitle.font.fontWithSize(18)
    self.myView.addSubview(documentsTitle)
    self.myView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: documentsTitle, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: subviews!.last, attribute: .Bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 12.0))
    self.myView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: documentsTitle, attribute: .Leading, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self.headerStackView, attribute: .Leading, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0))
    subviews?.append(documentsTitle)
    if  self.attachments.count > 0 {
        docTableView = UITableView()
        docTableView!.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        docTableView!.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "MenuCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "MenuCell")
        self.myView.addSubview(docTableView!)
        docTableView!.dataSource = self
        docTableView!.delegate = self
        self.myView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: docTableView!, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: subviews!.last, attribute: .Bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 5.0))
        self.myView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: docTableView!, attribute: .Leading, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self.headerStackView, attribute: .Leading, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0))
        self.myView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: docTableView!, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 300.0))
        self.docTableView?.reloadData()
        subviews?.append(docTableView!)
    }

    if notificationViewModel?.comments.count > 0 {
        commTableView = UITableView()
        commTableView?.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        commTableView!.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "CommentCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "CommentItemCell")
        self.myView.addSubview(commTableView!)
        self.myView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: commTableView!, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: subviews!.last, attribute: .Bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 5.0))
        self.myView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: commTableView!, attribute: .Leading, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self.headerStackView, attribute: .Leading, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0))
        subviews?.append(commTableView!)
        commTableView?.dataSource = self
        commTableView?.delegate = self
    }

    //TITLE
    let addCommentLabel = UILabel()
    addCommentLabel.text = "Добавьте свой комментарий"
    addCommentLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    addCommentLabel.textColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
    self.myView.addSubview(addCommentLabel)
    self.myView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: addCommentLabel, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: subviews!.last, attribute: .Bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 10.0))
    self.myView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: addCommentLabel, attribute: .Leading, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self.headerStackView, attribute: .Leading, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0))
    subviews?.append(addCommentLabel)

    let textField = UITextField()
    textField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    textField.borderStyle = .RoundedRect
    self.myView.addSubview(textField)
    self.myView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: textField, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: subviews!.last, attribute: .Bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 5.0))
    self.myView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: textField, attribute: .Leading, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self.headerStackView, attribute: .Leading, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0))
    self.myView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: textField, attribute: .Width, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self.myView, attribute: .Width, multiplier: 1.0, constant: -15))
    subviews?.append(textField)

    let sendButton = UIButton()
    sendButton.setTitle("Отправить", forState: .Normal)
    sendButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    sendButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
    sendButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.whiteColor(), forState: .Normal)
    self.myView.addSubview(sendButton)
    self.myView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: sendButton, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: subviews!.last, attribute: .Bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 5.0))
    self.myView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: textField, attribute: .Trailing, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: textField, attribute: .Trailing, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0))
    subviews?.append(sendButton)



    var height:CGFloat = 0.0
    for i in 0..<self.myView.subviews.count {
        height = height + myView.subviews[i].bounds.height
    }


    self.myView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.myView.frame.width, height: self.myView.frame.height + height)
    self.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.myView.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height + height)
    self.scrollView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.myView.frame.width, height: self.scrollView.frame.height + height)
    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: self.myView.frame.width, height: self.scrollView.frame.height + height)
    subviews  = nil
    self.viewUtils?.hideActivityIndicator(self.view)
}

func addPubDate(_subviews:[UIView], date:String, number:String) -> [UIView] {
    var subviews = _subviews
    let pubDateLabel = UILabel()
    pubDateLabel.text = "Дата публикации: " + UsefulClass.covertDataWithZ(date, withTime: false)
    pubDateLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    pubDateLabel.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    pubDateLabel.font = pubDateLabel.font.fontWithSize(11)
    self.myView.addSubview(pubDateLabel)
    self.myView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: pubDateLabel, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: subviews.last, attribute: .Bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 8.0))
    self.myView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: pubDateLabel, attribute: .Leading, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self.headerStackView, attribute: .Leading, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0))
    subviews.append(pubDateLabel)
    notificationUrlNumber(subviews, relatedView: pubDateLabel, number: number)
    return subviews
}
func notificationUrlNumber(subviews:[UIView], relatedView:UILabel, number:String) {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.text = "Извещение №: " + number
    label.textColor = UIColor.blueColor()

    setSimilarConstraintsToValuesLabels(label, relatedView: relatedView, _subViews: subviews)
}


//левый заголовок для поля
func addtitle(_title:String, _subviews:[UIView]) -> [UIView] {
    var subviews = _subviews
    let title = UILabel()
    title.text = _title
    title.numberOfLines = 0
    title.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    title.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    title.font = title.font.fontWithSize(18)
    self.myView.addSubview(title)
    self.myView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: title, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: subviews.last, attribute: .Bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 12.0))
    self.myView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: title, attribute: .Leading, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self.headerStackView, attribute: .Leading, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0))
    subviews.append(title)
    return subviews

}

//правое значение для информационого поля
func addTitleandValue(_title:String, _value:String, _subviews:[UIView], numberOfLines:Int) -> [UIView] {
    var subviews = _subviews
    let title = UILabel()
    title.text = _title
    title.font = title.font.fontWithSize(12)
    if subviews.count > 0 {
        setSimilarConstraintsToTitlesLabels(title, relatedView: (subviews.last!))
    } else {
        setSimilarConstraintsToTitlesLabels(title, relatedView: self.headerStackView)
    }

    let value = UILabel()
    value.text = _value
    value.numberOfLines = numberOfLines
    value.font = value.font.fontWithSize(12)
    subviews = setSimilarConstraintsToValuesLabels(value, relatedView: title, _subViews: subviews)
    return subviews
}


func addBoolEptrfValues(_title:String, _subviews:[UIView])->[UIView] {
    var subviews = _subviews
    let title = UILabel()
    title.text = _title
    title.numberOfLines = 0
    setSimilarConstraintsToTitlesLabels(title, relatedView: (subviews.last!))

    let value = UILabel()
    value.text = notificationViewModel?.convertBoolToString(true)
    value.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    subviews = setSimilarConstraintsToValuesLabels(value, relatedView: title, _subViews: subviews)

    return subviews
}

func addDeleteButton(subviews:[UIView], isDeleted:Bool) -> UILabel {
    let deleteLabel = UILabel()
    if isDeleted == false {
        deleteLabel.text = "Удалить"
    } else {
        deleteLabel.text = "Восстановить"
    }
    deleteLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    deleteLabel.textColor = UIColor.blueColor()
    deleteLabel.font = deleteLabel.font.fontWithSize(11)
    self.myView.addSubview(deleteLabel)
    self.myView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: deleteLabel, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: subviews.last, attribute: .Bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 8.0))
    self.myView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: deleteLabel, attribute: .Leading, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self.headerStackView, attribute: .Leading, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0))
    return deleteLabel
}


//right values next to the title
func setSimilarConstraintsToValuesLabels(subView:UILabel, relatedView:UILabel, _subViews:[UIView]) -> [UIView] {
    var subViews = _subViews
    subView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    self.myView.addSubview(subView)

    if (relatedView.text?.characters.count < 35 && subView.text?.characters.count < 30) {
        self.myView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: subView, attribute: .Right, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self.myView, attribute: .Right, multiplier: 1.0, constant: -15))
        self.myView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: subView, attribute: .Left, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: relatedView, attribute: .Right, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 5))
        self.myView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: subView, attribute: .FirstBaseline, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: relatedView, attribute: .LastBaseline, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0))
    } else {
        self.myView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: subView, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: relatedView, attribute: .Bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 8.0))
        self.myView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: subView, attribute: .Leading, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self.headerStackView, attribute: .Leading, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 8.0))
        self.myView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: subView, attribute: .Width, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self.myView, attribute: .Width, multiplier: 1.0, constant: -15))
        self.myView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: relatedView, attribute: .Width, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self.myView, attribute: .Width, multiplier: 1.0, constant: -15))
        subViews.append(relatedView)
    }

    subViews.append(subView)


    return subViews
}


func setSimilarConstraintsToTitlesLabels(subView:UILabel, relatedView:UIView) {
    subView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    subView.textColor = UIColor.grayColor()
    subView.numberOfLines = 0
    self.myView.addSubview(subView)
    self.myView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: subView, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: relatedView, attribute: .Bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 8.0))
    self.myView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: subView, attribute: .Leading, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self.headerStackView, attribute: .Leading, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0))
}
}
```

The method "informationUpdate()" is called when information for showing is parsed.

Comment: Try `addSubView` function in parent view instead of append view to an array like that

Comment: I guess it is already like this : self.myView.addSubview(docTableView!). Adding it to the array "subviews" will help me to know the position of the last element in the view

Comment: just set background color of tableView as red (or some thing other than same color as view background), then you can observe did tableView added to your view or not

Comment: Ok. It is not red. So it is not even added. Why is it so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your tableView has no height Constraint, so the height is set to 0.
Then no cell are visible => cellForRow never called :)

Comment: Yeah, I thought of it. I set a constraint to the tableview and unfortunately all I see is the empty space. There are not cells, just empty white space between top and bottom related subviews. 
May be I am doing this wrong? "self.myView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: docTableView!, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .Height, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 300.0))"

Comment: try to set a red background to see if there is an empty table view or no tableview at all

Comment: @LisaSemyonova yes, this is wrong. You should setup height constraint like this: `myView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: docTableView!, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 300.0))`. Attention on **.NotAnAttribute**. Also, it is easier to share some larger piece of code instead of this questing..

Comment: @ShadowOf I have just added my ViewController's code. Hope that helps to understand.

Comment: I'll take a look in the day ;)

Comment: @LisaSemyonova you are mixing autolayout with frames in `informationUpdate()`. At the end of this function you trying to setup height for `myView`. But if some (all?) of your views use autolayout, and their actual height will be available in `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` method of `UIViewController`. So far, `height` value can not be right in `informationUpdate()`. For debug, you can try to setup it for big value (1000?); also add _width_ constraint for docTableView. Note that _height_ and _width_ constraints better to add to view itself (`docTableView!.addConstraint(...)`), not to superview.

Comment: @ShadowOf Thank you very much! I appreciate all the comments you have said to me. It worked after I set height and width constraints to the docTableView itself as you said.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try to create more clear code. Do not use "blind" array of `subviews`; do not append views directly to `subviews` property, you already added it to view hierarchy; if you use autolayout (`translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false`) - don't try mix it with frames in single view, go and set up all constraints; use different background colors for different views to debug view hierarchy at runtime; go to Xcode *Debug\View Debugging\Capture View Hierarchy* for deep explore view hierarchy at runtime

Also, if `numberOfRowsInSection` did called by `UITableView` and return value > 0 (check it!), then `cellForRowAtIndexPath` **must** be called immediately by this `UITableView` since `dataSource` property is set. If you have more than one `UITableView` objects - check if there is no unexpected replaces.

P.S. if you from Russia I can help on Russian lang

Comment: @LisaSemyonova please post in english only.this is english site.I have flagged your comment.

Comment: @Neel sorry for that, we will post solution in english if we will find it, but I ask for russian for better understanding, I believe in comments this is better then unresolved question.